# Silverlight Popup: How do I call a method after popup is opened?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, events, popup

I'm working with a Silverlight Popup control (SL4). I would like to update data shown on that popup every time the user opens it (IsOpen=true) by passing a string and calling a Private method located in the Popup control behind code to fetch updated data.

I was hoping to place code to make this happen in the Opened event of the Popup, but such an event does not seem to exist (even though I found some documentation on it).

I'm doing this in VB.

Comment: The `Opened` event definitely exists (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.opened.aspx). I've even used it. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: I pulled up the Events list for the Popup control and it was not listed (the combobox where the DragOver, Drop, etc. events are listed). Bear in mind, I'm new to .Net...I'm sure I'm missing something!

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely an Opened Event Handler

Namespace:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
```

Code:

```
 Popup popup = new Popup();
 popup.Opened += (s, args) =>
 {
    // do work
 };
```